# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE field mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am working on a new project, a web application in PHP that requires user input of a potentially large data set.  My solution is to have the user upload a csv file, which I then add to my mysql database with the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command.

My test csv:

```
NUMBER,ADDRESS,COMMENT,SCOUTMASTER_NAME,SCOUTMASTER_EMAIL,COMMITTEE_NAME,COMMITTEE_EMAIL,DISTRICT
4,404 test st.,so cool,bob jones,bob@jones.com,tim hanson,tim@hanson.net,western trails
5,404 test st.,so cool,bob jones,bob@jones.com,tim hanson,tim@hanson.net,western trails
6,404 test st.,so cool,bob jones,bob@jones.com,tim hanson,tim@hanson.net,western trails
7,404 test st.,so cool,bob jones,bob@jones.com,tim hanson,tim@hanson.net,western trails
```

Result of the `DESCRIBE` command on the `TROOPS` table:

```
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| NUMBER              | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| ADDRESS             | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COMMENT             | varchar(2048) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SCOUTMASTER_NAME    | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SCOUTMASTER_EMAIL   | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COMMITTEE_NAME      | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| COMMITTEE_EMAIL     | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PRIMARY_ELENGOMAT   | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SECONDARY_ELENGOMAT | int(255)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DISTRICT            | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ELECTION_DATE       | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MEMBERS             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The relevant PHP:

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$uploadedFile' 
          INTO TABLE TROOPS 
          FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
          OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
          LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
          IGNORE 1 LINES  
          (NUMBER,ADDRESS,COMMENT,SCOUTMASTER_NAME,
           SCOUTMASTER_EMAIL,COMMITTEE_NAME,COMMITTEE_EMAIL,DISTRICT) ";

$result = $db->query($query);
```

Output of `SELECT` command (note: this is exactly the console output, with the strange spaces):

```
+--------+--------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+
| NUMBER | ADDRESS      | COMMENT | SCOUTMASTER_NAME | SCOUTMASTER_EMAIL | COMMITTEE_NAME | COMMITTEE_EMAIL | PRIMARY_ELENGOMAT | SECONDARY_ELENGOMAT | DISTRICT        | ELECTION_DATE | MEMBERS |
+--------+--------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+
|      0 | 404 test st. | so cool | bob jones        | bob@jones.com     | tim hanson     | tim@hanson.net  |              NULL |                NULL | western trails  | NULL          |    NULL |
 | NULL          |    NULL | cool | bob jones        | bob@jones.com     | tim hanson     | tim@hanson.net  |              NULL |                NULL | western trails
 | NULL          |    NULL | cool | bob jones        | bob@jones.com     | tim hanson     | tim@hanson.net  |              NULL |                NULL | western trails
 | NULL          |    NULL | cool | bob jones        | bob@jones.com     | tim hanson     | tim@hanson.net  |              NULL |                NULL | western trails
|      7 | 404 test st. | so cool | bob jones        | bob@jones.com     | tim hanson     | tim@hanson.net  |              NULL |                NULL | western trails  | NULL          |    NULL |
+--------+--------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+
```

The errors and the warnings table are both empty.

My question is, "What do I need to tweak in order to properly import this data?"

It's obvious to me that something strange is happening here, especially how the non-nullable primary key 'number' is null, and how the test string 'so cool' is cut off in the middle for three of the inputs.  I'm guessing its something with line breaks, I've tried \n, \r, \r\n, and \n\r for the `LINES TERMINATED BY` parameter.

Comment: It looks like some of your fields have a `\r` in the middle of them. Maybe some of your lines end with just `\r` and not `\r\n`?

Comment: Actually, it looks like some of the lines may end with `\r\r\n`. So `DISTRICT` is being set to `western trails\r`.

Comment: Good idea, Any tips on how I can check the file for escaped characters?

Comment: what was the original source of this csv file ?

Comment: I can confirm there is nothing wrong with your query. I just replicated a TROOPs MySQL table with exact data types and ran exact `LOAD DATA INFILE` on posted csv. Data renders fine with no strange nulls and spaces. Consider using PHP to read CSV and replace those delimiter characters.

Comment: Use a hex editor or file dump utility.

Comment: The source of this csv is a google sheet.  I just selected 'download as a csv'.  I had hoped that there was a standard csv format, but I'm beginning to see that that's not the case.

Comment: that really should not be adding any weird code.

Comment: Could it be relevant that I'm running this in [Cloud9](http://c9.io)?  Or maybe the CSV is getting mangled in the upload.

Comment: Unfortunately for anyone else having this issue I have since moved development on this project away from PHP to golang, so I doubt I'll ever find a fix.  Best of luck!